# Proposed tag merge: grid and grid-layout

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tagging, tag-synonyms

We seem to have redundant tags: [grid](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grid) and [grid-layouts](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grid-layouts).  Nearly all of the questions tagged [grid](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grid) are about grid-layouts.  (We also have [lightweight-grid](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lightweight-grid) for questions about that product.)  I propose that these tags be made synonymous.  Please vote  accordingly for one of the three options below.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, make [grid](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grid) a synonym of [grid-layouts](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grid-layouts); [grid-layouts](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grid-layouts) will be used hereafter.

Comment: I think I like this suggestion more... it helps to clarify the _concept_, while avoiding any confusion with alternate meanings for the function name. There are several minor function name based tags that have slowly crept up and are often confusing. For example, [tag:map] which could be either list-manipulation or cartographic maps, [tag:table] which could either be `Table` or tabular grids (Excel sheets, `TableForm`, etc.). These will need to be cleaned up at some point.

Comment: You should probably just go ahead and do this.

Comment: @Shog9 Yes, I shall.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, make [grid-layouts](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grid-layouts) a synonym of [grid](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grid); [grid](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grid) will be used hereafter.

Answer (score 0):

No, don't make these tags synonymous.